# Complex ($\mathbb C$) least squares derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I know how to derive the least squares in the real domain.

If a tall matrix $A$ and a column vector $b$ are real,
then the solution of the least squares problem $Ax = b$ can be derived as:

$$\begin{align}
\{E(x)\}^2 &= ||Ax - b||^2 \\
&= (Ax-b)^T (Ax-b) \\
&= x^T A^T Ax - x^T A^T b - b^T Ax + b^T b \\
&= x^T A^T Ax - 2 x^T A^T b + b^T b \qquad (\because (Ax)^T b = b^T (Ax))
\end{align}$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d \{E(x)\}^2}{dx} &= 2A^T Ax - 2 A^T b
\end{align}$$

Setting $\frac{d \{E(x)\}^2}{dx} = 0$ to find when we get the minimum $E(x)$,

$$
2A^T Ax - 2 A^T b = 0 \\
A^T Ax = A^T b \\
x = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b
$$

Now, we turn to the complex-valued situation.
Assume $A$ and $b$ are complex,

$$\begin{align}
\{E(x)\}^2 &= ||Ax - b||^2 \\
&= (Ax-b)^H (Ax-b) \\
&= x^H A^H Ax - x^H A^H b - b^H Ax + b^H b \\
\end{align}$$

Here, I have some problems.
First, $x^H A^H b \neq b^H Ax$ unless $(Ax)^H b$ is real.
Most of all, I don't know how to differentiate the complex matrices above.

How to proceed the derivation?
There are plenty of derivations in the real domain in Google, but I couldn't find detailed explanation of the general complex case.

Comment: Hint: decompose in real and imaginary parts and differentiate on the real vectors $x_r$ and $x_i$ separately: $\|(A_rx_r-A_ix_i-b_r)+i(A_ix_r+A_rx_i-b_i)\|^2$.

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/analysis-with-complex-data-anything-different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Denote the complex conjugate, transpose, and conjugate transpose of the matrix $A$ as $(A^*, A^T, A^H)$ respectively.

Use the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) to write the function and take its differential
$$\eqalign{
  f &= (Ax-b)^*:(Ax-b) \cr\cr
 df &= (Ax-b)^*:A\,dx \cr
    &= A^T(Ax-b)^*:dx \cr
}$$
Since $df=\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}:dx\Big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= A^T(Ax-b)^* \cr
}$$
Set the gradient to zero, take the complex conjugate, and solve for $x$
$$\eqalign{
 A^T(Ax)^* &= A^Tb^* \cr
 A^HAx &= A^Hb \cr
 x &= (A^HA)^{-1}A^Hb \cr
   &= A^{+}b \cr
}$$
Notice that $x$ and $x^*$ are treated as independent variables for the purpose of differentiation.

Comment: "Notice that  and ∗ are treated as independent variables for the purpose of differentiation." -- It's clear that this works out here, but what is the intuition for treating x and x* as independent? In what contexts does this trick work?

Comment: @Kipton every context. Clearly $(1, 1)$ and $(1, -1)$ are linearly independent, and equally so are $1+i$ and $1-i$ when taken as a vector over $\mathbb R^2$ (one dimensional things are always linearly dependent so it's pointless to talk about $\mathbb C$). Note that the latter is the complex conjugate of the former. You can also verify that $\frac{\textrm d}{\textrm dz}\bar z = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. This finally clicked for me when I saw the formal definition of the [Wirtinger derivativative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Formal_definition), $\partial / \partial z = (1/2) (\partial / \partial x - i \partial / \partial y)$ where $z = x + i y$, which generalizes the usual complex derivative to non-holomorphic functions. With this definition, you automatically get nice properties like the ones you mentioned, as well as the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Chain_rule) (effectively treating $z$ and $\bar z$ as independent).