# Estimating parameters using 0-1 matrix system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, matrix-equations, parameter-estimation

I have the following set of $n$ equations:

$ \hspace{4cm}\boxed{y^{(1)}=h_1x_1^{(1)}+ h_2x_2^{(1)} +\ldots+ h_kx_k^{(1)} +w_1\\ y^{(2)}=h_1x_1^{(2)}+ h_2x_2^{(2)} +\ldots+ h_kx_k^{(2)}+w_2\\ \vdots  \\ y^{(n)}=h_1x_1^{(n)}+ h_2x_2^{(n)} +\ldots+ h_kx_k^{(n)}+w_n}$

In matrix notation, $ \boxed{\vec{y}= \textbf{X}\vec{h}+\vec{w}},$ where,

> $\vec{h}=[h_1,h_2,\ldots, h_k]$ denotes the coefficients where each
> entry is a complex number.
>
> $\vec{y}=[y_1,y_2,\ldots, y_n]$  is the output vector.
>
> The $ (i,j)^{th}$ entry of matrix $\textbf{X}$ is given by
> $\textbf{X}_{ij}=x_i^{(j)}$.
>
> $w_j, \forall j \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$  is  IID Gaussian noise distributed as $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$.
>
> Also $n>k$.

In my problem setup,  $x_i^{(j)} \in \{0,1\}$ and their values are **known**.   My aim is to estimate the coefficients $h_i'^s$.

**Question 1**:  What constraints the 0-1 Binary matrix $\textbf{X}$ needs to satisfy so that I can get proper estimates of $h_i'^s, \forall i \in\{1,2,\ldots, k\}.$

*Comment*: I have not quantitatively elaborated what a "proper estimate" means. I am happy with any  good standard estimates. I would like to know what conditions on $\textbf{X}$  could potentially help me to proceed with finding the standard estimates like MLE/MMSE or Least squares or something else.

Comment: Well, it seems that $\boldsymbol{X}^{H}\boldsymbol{X}$ should be invertible. Then, you can use (complex) least squares to get an estimator of $\vec{h}$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783397/complex-mathbb-c-least-squares-derivation) for details.

Comment: @d.k.o. Could you elaborate why $\textbf{X}^H\textbf{X}$ seems to be invertible? Is it right to say that the matrix $\textbf{X}$ needs to be a disjunct matrix for $\textbf{X}^H\textbf{X}$ to be invertible? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_matrix)