# Rank of a tall binary matrix with IID Bernoulli entries with probability function of size.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, determinant

I have a binary matrix composed of $0's$ and $1's$. $\textbf{X}$ of size $(n,k)$ where $n>k$.

The entries of the matrix are **Bernoulli random variables**. Specifically, the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry $X_{ij} \sim Bern(q), \forall i,j.$ Also, $X_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$. Note that  $X_{ij}$ are **independent  random variables** $\forall i,j.$

I am operating on the field $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question**: $\boxed{\text{What is the probability that Rank(X)=$k$  if $q=1-2^{-1/k}$.}}$

Moreover, in my case, $\boxed{n= C \times k \log k \text{ where C>0 is a constant such that $n>k$.}} $

**Can someone provide a  characterization of $Rank(\textbf{X})$ in terms of $q$ and $n$**.

Are there results in the literature which talks about *"tall Bernoulli matrices" with probability as a function of the matrix dimension*? Tight bounds are ok too.

> **The context**: [Estimating parameters using 0-1 matrix system of equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339302/estimating-parameters-using-0-1-matrix-system-of-equations?noredirect=1#comment9050907_4339302)
>
> To find the least squares estimate, I need to find the psuedo-inverse
> of $\textbf{X}$. The least squares estimate is only a good one, if the
> matrix $\textbf{X}$ is  non-singular and well-conditioned.

Comment: My sense is that this problem is too complicated in its full generality. See Theorem A in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.09016.pdf) for a recent answer of an old conjecture for $n=k$.

Comment: Your question is unusual because: (i) If $a=0.5$ then $1-a^{-1/k}<0$ and cannot be a probability; (ii) The main reason I can see to make the Bernoulli probability a function of $k$ is to take $k\rightarrow \infty$, which makes it impossible to preserve $n>k$ unless we also take $n\rightarrow\infty$ in some way.

Comment: @Michael, In my case $a$ is such that $q$ is a valid probability value. In fact, I will rewrite the question with $a=2$ to make it simpler. Also,  actually $n=C \times k \log k $  for a constant $C>0$.  I will add these details to the question.

Comment: One can say something if there are i.i.d. assumptions introduced.  For example if entries are i.i.d. and $c<1/\log(2)$ then the probability that at least one column is all-zero goes to 1 as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What is the context of this question?  (I don't suppose we will ever know...)

Comment: @Michael $X_{ij}'s$ are iid RVs. I forgot to mention that. 
$\textbf{The context}$: Basically, I have a set of equations  in matrix form $y=hX+n$. The $X$ is as described here.  I want to estimate $h$ from $y$. I am trying to use least squares estimate, but it requires $X$ to be full-rank.

Comment: Do you have any conjectures? Have you tried some Monte-Carlo estimates?

Comment: Why do you use the format $q = 1 - 2^{-1/k}$, and $n = ck\log(k)$? These seem crafted to take the asymptotics as $k\rightarrow\infty$ of the probability of having at least one column of all-zeros.

Comment: @Michael, That $q$ was found to be optimal for the system I am designing. So are you saying  for any value of constant $c$, the rank will be less than $k$ asymptotically?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the entries are i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P[X_{ij}=1]=1-(1/2)^{1/k}$, where $k$ is the number of columns. Assume the number of rows is $n=c k \log(k)$ for some $c>0$.

The probability that a single column is all-zero is
$$ P[\mbox{Col 1 is all-zero}]=(1/2)^{n/k} = (1/2)^{c \log(k)} = \frac{1}{k^{c\log(2)}}$$
The probability that no columns are all-zero is:
$$ P[\mbox{No columns are all-zero}]=\left(1 - \frac{1}{k^{c\log(2)}}\right)^k$$
Thus
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} P[\mbox{No columns are all-zero}] = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{ if $0<c<\frac{1}{\log(2)}$} \\
1/e & \mbox{ if $c=\frac{1}{\log(2)}$}\\
1 & \mbox{ if $c>\frac{1}{\log(2)}$} 
\end{array}\right.$$
where $\frac{1}{\log(2)} \approx 1.442695$. If a matrix has at least one all-zero column then it cannot be full rank.  Thus, assuming $0<c<\frac{1}{\log(2)}$ we have
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} P[\mbox{Full rank}] = 0$$
The case $c>\frac{1}{\log(2)}$ can perhaps make use of the approximations here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330669/rank-of-a-random-sparse-matrix-with-nonnegative-reals

Comment: I suspect that $P[Full rank]\rightarrow 1$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ if $c>1/\log(2)$, since each column will have a handful of randomly placed 1s, though it seems hard to prove.